# Unclogging sink drain

Tags: drain, sink, clog

My bathroom sink drain is clogged. I tried to use a hanger to remove whatever was blocking it up, and I got a nice chunk. But, I saw it was still clogged. There is a semi clear piece under the sink that is bendable. I removed that, but it seemed clear. It seems to me that the clog is in the bend in the pipe below that. I was not able to get anything out with my hanger, and I don't see a way to remove that piece. Any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: do you have have a pic of your undersink area.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is for you to procure a drum style *drain auger* and clear the drain with it. It is a worthwhile investment and will pay for itself many times over, once you become proficient with it.

I recommend a professional quality auger, because they work better and last forever if taken care of properly.

[image]

Comment: I agree. The right tool for the job..  leave the hangers for clothes..

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this one a good auger for a home-owner? Or is something better more better? :-) Suggestions?  <https://www.amazon.com/Drainx-50-FT-Plumbing-Gloves-Storage/dp/B07J4Z19QW> Thanks, Rich

Comment: I have no familiarity with that brand but the plastic pistol-grip concerns me. A common point of failure of low=end units is the thumb screw that holds the cable while driving. It needs to be loosened and tightened frequently and seeing it threaded into plastic would make me never consider purchasing. Also, professional grade augers usually brag about the stiffening core in the cable, this makes no such claims which means it might be soft like a wet noodle.

Answer (score 0):

One of these claw tools may get the job done:

[image]

Comment: like this? https://www.amazon.com/Remover-Cleaning-Kitchen-Bathroom-Stainless/dp/B08FY5QVPK/ref=sr_1_36?dchild=1&keywords=drain+auger&qid=1608480515&sr=8-36

Comment: Yep.  In my opinion, if there is some object in there, you are better off pulling it out rather than pushing it further in.